# Cordova Icon is missing when I specify an icon

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, icons, config

I am creating an app and I am wrapping it in Cordova. when I go into the config.xml to setup a icon, it seems to work but when I emulate the app the icon isn't the one I created. its not the default Cordova one either, instead it's a weird grid with 3 circles. I think this is the icon that shows up when an image has not loaded on iOS. Does anyone know if this is normal? is it supposed to happen? when I go into my platform/iOS folder and go into where the icons are the icons are setup there.

config.xml

```
    <icon src="www/img/icon.png" />
```

example of icon:

https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/34bc9e44-723c-4e06-b86d-88860b388a42